# Model/View Separation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, game-engine

Let's say I am making a video game. The player has an X and a Y coordinate, and these values are members of the `Player` object. Let us also assume I am using the hypothetical `GAME-X` game engine, which renders each object using the `GX_x` and `GX_y` values.

If I want to separate the domain (`Player`) from the view (`GAME-X`), it is my understanding that the player should have its own `X` and `Y` coordinates which are manipulated independently, and the `GX_x` and `GX_y` simply "listen" to the player's current coordinates. Doing this would allow me to, for example, choose a new game engine while leaving the domain layer untouched. It also means that the game can essentially run on a strictly domain level.

Is this a good design strategy? If not, why? If so, what is the real name for this strategy and how can I improve upon on it throughout my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> player should have its own X and Y coordinates which are manipulated
>   independently, and the GX_x and GX_y simply "listen" to the player's
>   current coordinates.

That's correct strategy. Since `GX_x`, `GX_y` are presentation level and can be device / resolution / engine specific.

Consider 2 phones with `480*320` and `960*640` resolutions. `x`,`y` in your model should be the same (the same code running in both phones) whereas `GX_x` and `GX_y` will be different on both devices.

It is [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern you're talking about.

> choose a new game engine while leaving the domain layer untouched. It
>   also means that the game can essentially run on a strictly domain
>   level.

These are advantages and reasons for the pattern to be used.